# How do you choose specific id and time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this small program in C# that is constantly sending data to one of my tables (DataTable). The data format is always the same as well as the length.

There are 4 different `ID`s I am working with here: 2000,2001,2002, ...which are all in a different table. The `ID` column is the foreign key in my `DataTable` column.

Initially I thought I could just retrieve the last inserted row in my `DataTable` for a specific `ID`. However, I realized that the insert statement does allocate the values into the database in the order they are sent. Therefore, I decided to simply take an `ID` and get the last row of data based on the timestamp.

I have tried using `DatePart` but this limits me to only hours. I would want to display a time based on hours and min. ex: `2002 between '4:30:00' and '5:30:00'`.

Also, would I have to do a join statement since I would be calling the `ID` column from another table?

Ive tried this so far: `

```
use LogDatabase
select * from dbo.DataTable
join CustomerTable
on(Customer_ID = CustIDFk)
where DATEPART(HH, TimeStamp)between 4 and 5  `
```

The incoming data string looks alot like this:

```
3-13-2011 3:30:21 2002: 45 Temp:81 Albany NY etc....
```

I have made columns for the every field of data in my DataTable. As you can see
2002 is the ID which is called Customer_ID in my CustomerTable. I have set this
as my primary key in the CustomerTable and CustIDFk is the foreign key to be linked
with Customer_ID. As you can see, I'm trying to join my Customer table with my Data 
table in order to specify the ID. The DATEPART statement allows to give a time range 
by either hour or min among others but does not allow a "between 4:30 and 5:30.

Comment: You need to show some example data and whatever queries you've written so far - even if they aren't working.

Comment: I agree with Yuck. At present, this doesn't makes much sense to me. Table definition and some sample data will answer a truckload of questions we would have to ask to understand your problem.

Comment: @Rick: please **do not post** code samples and stuff like that into comments - **REALLY HARD** to read! Please instead: **update** your original question to provide more information!

Comment: Can you not just do a MAX on the date?

Comment: @Simon, yes I plan to use a Max on date to receive the most recent row inserted. However, my application is time specific. I need the most recent row or rows at a specific time range. ex: 4:30 - 5:30 or 4:10-4:20 (something where I can manipulate the min.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)

SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.DataTable
WHERE   TIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, 30, DATEADD(hh, 4, @today)) AND DATEADD(hh, 5, @today)
```